# XHR onProgress completed

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, progress

I'm trying to implement a label with the percentaje of upload using ajax. The problem is that after the xhr returned 100%, it still takes about 17 seconds until the readyState==4 and status==200.

I am sending a picture (png/jpg) and strings using FormData() object

```
<form onclick='send(this)'....
```

and the function is:

```
function send(form){ var f = new FormData(form).......
```

I am using the following code for the upload

```
if(xhr.upload) {
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var perc = Math.round((e.loaded/e.total) * 100);
            var state = {
                'done': e.loaded,
                'total': e.total,
                'percent': perc
            };
            progress(state);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: the old way... if readystate!=4 it will be 99%

Comment: So is it perfectly normal? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: its not normal.you should satisfy user . is it. if it is not actually ended and it shows 100% thats not correct. so show 99% till it end.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I meant if the fact that the percent is returning 100% when obviously it isnt finished happens all the time, or my code is broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely an issue with your server, not your client-side code.  Your `onreadystatechange` handler will be called with a `readyState` value of 4 only after the server has returned a response to the underlying request.  The loaded/total values passed into your `onprogress` handler indicate the number of bytes that have been sent to the server.  If total === loaded, this does not necessarily indicate that the server has returned a response.  The server may perform some processing after the last byte has been received, and then return a response (triggering your `onreadstatechange` handler).  If you are noticing a long period of time between sending of the last byte and the invocation of your `onreadystatechange` handler, this indicates that your server is, for whatever reason, taking its time responding to the request.